# How to get MultiSeat (loginctl attach) to properly work with a MultiStreamDisplayPort card?

Tags: multiple-monitors, displayport, multiseat, hardware-certification

The native display on this All-in-One is the ...**/card0/card0-LVDS-1** and the DisplayPort attached external monitor is
...**/drm/card0/card0-DP-2**

Was hoping to keep the LVDS as the embedded All-in-One and use one of the DP ports as the external monitor in a multiseat setup.   However, loginctl attach seat1 /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.0/drm/card0/card0-DP-2  not only moves DP-2 to seat1, but all the ports on card0.

```
              ├─/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.0/drm/card0
              │ [MASTER] drm:card0
              │ ├─/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.0/drm/card0/card0-DP-1
              │ │ [MASTER] drm:card0-DP-1
              │ ├─/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.0/drm/card0/**card0-DP-2**
              │ │ [MASTER] drm:card0-DP-2
              │ ├─/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.0/drm/card0/card0-DP-3
              │ │ [MASTER] drm:card0-DP-3
              │ ├─/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.0/drm/card0/card0-DP-4
              │ │ [MASTER] drm:card0-DP-4
              │ ├─/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.0/drm/card0/**card0-LVDS-1**
              │ │ [MASTER] drm:card0-LVDS-1
              │ └─/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.0/drm/card0/card0-VGA-1
              │   [MASTER] drm:card0-VGA-1
              ├─/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.0/drm/renderD128
              │ drm:renderD128
              ├─/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.0/graphics/fb0
              │ [MASTER] graphics:fb0 "radeondrmfb"
```